# Sending push notification without configuring APNs authentication key

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

In official firebase documentation it is said that

> For FCM specifically, you'll need to upload your APNs authentication key and register for remote notifications.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

Is it possible to send push notification without configuring a APNs authentication key in firebase console?

If it is not possible then why?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, since the APNs says it in the very name, Push Notification Services, if you don't configure that then you'll be sending your notifications to nothing, I understand that's how your project will know were it's receiving the notifications from, so it can process them and sending to your app.